# On one example involving the mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let me first remind you of what the theorem states (mainly for you to understand the notation):

*If $f(x)$ is continuous in the closed interval $[x_1;x_2]$ and differentiable at every point of the open interval $(x_1;x_2)$, then there is at least one point $\xi \in (x_1;x_2)$ such that*

$$ \frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1} = f’(\xi)$$

I have been asked to determine the value of $\xi = \xi(x_1,x_2)$, given that $$ f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 + 1}.$$ The problem is that when I obtained the derivative $f’(x)$ and, given the definition of $f(x)$, rewrote the expression from the theorem and simplified it, I arrived at the following equation: $$\xi^4 + 2\xi^2 - 2p\xi + 1 = 0,$$ where $$ p \equiv \frac{(x_1^2 + 1)(x_2^2 + 1)}{x_1 + x_2}.$$ The form of the equation, which is a quartic (though a depressed one, but that does not make the matters easier), suggests that there exist several roots of rather complicated form, but when I look at the graph of $f(x)$, I see that almost always there is a singular value of $\xi$ (checking by means of the geometric interpretation of the mean value theorem) which satisfies the theorem.

The questions is whether it is possible to avoid the cumbersome encounter with the quartic, or it is something I shall inevitably face in order to solve the problem?

I also desire to ask you to propose **hints only**. I want to solve the problem myself, for otherwise I will not be able to learn.

Comment: Mathematica confirm your intuition that the roots of that quartic do not have any nice form. In what context have you been asked to do this? It's hard for me to believe that this type of problem serves any pedagogical purpose.

Comment: @GregMartin Courant’s “Differential and Integral Calculus, Vol.1” Page 109, examples section, exercise 3 (d).

Comment: These are old books, it is possible there are errata. For instance if you consider $\frac x{x^2+1}$ it turns into a more appealing quadratic in $\xi^2$.